# Is it possible to export contacts from users salesforce accounts using external application (php)

Tags: api, oauth2, php, app

So I'm building an application which exports contacts from various CRMs and unifies that data to run marketing reports on their contacts.

I was easily able to get HubSpot and InfusionSoft working with their Oauth2 apis, and I was hoping that salesforce would go just as easily.

My desired flow is to redirect the user from their private domain (e.g. `user1.appDomain.com`) to the salesforce site to log them in.
Then I want to redirect them back to their private domain (`user1.appDomain.com/oauthReturn`) with their access token so I can start importing their data.

I registered an external application in my developer salesforce account, and have received my oauth tokens, but I need to know a few things (that googling hasn't solved yet).

So I need to know a few things first.

- Will salesforce allow me to pass in the redirect url from the user's private domain?
- Can I even do this with Oauth2 and php? The documentation is unnecessarily confusing, and most of the libraries are still using api tokens and all of the relevant documentation I can find is 2-3 years out of date.

If anyone knows where I should be looking to find these answers that would be extraordinarily helpful.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Or if this is too much to ask, is it possible to export an external user's salesforce contacts with the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Spring-15-Use-Multiple-Callback-URLs-for-Connected-Apps&language=en_US

This help article is just a notice saying that you can enter in multiple return urls, rather than specifying a wildcard, but since we're programmatically spinning up subdomains, this means I might have to drop salesforce support.

!!EDIT!!
Actually, there is a {state} variable you can pass into the GET call to the authorize endpoint which will return to your redirectUrl. So instead of specifying a wildcard callback url, you can specify a centralized one and pass in a (url encoded) identifier and redirect the user back to their proper location. Kinda a hack, but working with salesforce always seems to be so.

Also, for logging in a user and getting access to their salesforce account via oauth, I think the flow is going to be:

GET:

> https://\login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&state={whatever_you_want_sent_to_the_redirect_url}

Which returns a GET code to your redirect Url, which then in turn is posted over to

POST:

> https://\login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
>
> code: {access code you just received}
>
> grant_type: 'authorization_code'
>
> client_id: {from app config}
>
> client_id: {from app config}
>
> redirect_uri: {from app config}

However I cannot get my security settings to work so I always get an error, but it does seem that what I was asking is possible.

This just gets your oauth tokens which you can use to get the contact info (I'll post when I get past my authentication issue)

If I'm doing anything else wrong I'll update the answer.